# Isn't this patent abusive?

Tags: us9729556

In reference to the patent: [US9729556](https://www.google.com/patents/US9729556)

Hello,

Open Badges have been invented in 2011.
https://openbadges.org/about/#history
and digital badging has a longer history.

So, how can there be a patent for this and a man called John Arlan Brock claiming he's the inventor?!?

Comment: A better link to the patent is: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9729556B2/en. You can see the figures here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to preface this answer with the fact that I'm not an attorney nor expert in this field so don't take any of this as legal opinion.

There are a couple of possibilities here. First, it is possible that the cited patent is merely an incremental improvement to an existing technology. In that case, the detailed specifics of the claims would relate the novel improvement. However, in that case, I would have expected the patent specification to cite the earlier implementation and describe how the new implementation is different and improved. I could find no reference to OpenBadges.org (which clearly existed before the filing of the application) in the patent.

Second and perhaps more likely is that the USPTO when searching for prior art, limited itself to patent literature only. There are 113 prior patent citations listed, but no non-patent citations. In this case, the USPTO could be unaware of openbadges.org. The inventor works for Salesforce.com which is the assignee. Salesforce is a large and sophisticated organization so I would be surprised if it was unaware of openbadges.org.

Bottom line is in my less than expert opinion, I think you are justified in questioning the validity of this patent. There are provisions to challenge an issued patent. A [Post Grant Review](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/appealing-patent-decisions/trials/post-grant-review) can be filed within 9 months of the grant date. Unfortunately, there is a fee for filing this challenge. I would certainly make the issue known to those in the Open Badges organization and perhaps reach out to the [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org).